# Why do we add properties of model in ApplicationDbContext class that is generated by the visual studio

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I was going through a tutorial and found something like this.
couldn't find out why the properties of a model class (i.e., Customers,Movies,..) are added to this context class that is auto-generated in the ASP.net MVC individual authentication template.

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MembershipType> MembershipTypes { get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

Comment: `DbSet<Entity>` is a class form EntityFramework that represents a entity or a table in a database and the `Customers, Movies..` are the names of these tables.

Comment: To expand a bit on what @Llazar said, imagine you have 1000 models in your application. Not all of these models will need to have corresponding database tables but are instead only used to logically group together some data. Defining DbSets gives you a way of telling EntityFramework which classes/entities should be used to interact with the DB. This explanation is oversimplified by quite a bit- just trying to give a relate-able example that may help you

Comment: How else would you access any of the classes in the database?

Comment: *auto-generated* - Well, there's always a source for auto-generation. We don't know that source so it's kinda hard to answer this.

Comment: But my doubt is regarding why `DbSet` has been added to this `ApplicationDbContext` which is dealing with the identity authorization.

Comment: @GregH Thanks for the explanation. Did you mean to say they were added to tell the EntityFramework which classes should interact with the DB ?